# Dark theme issue in Above Android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, themes, darkmode, android-dark-theme

In my app theme I changed to dark mode but not reflecting in Splash screen after updating Splash screen API. So I refer to developers documentation in that they mentioned Above Android 12 we should use UiModeManager#setApplicationNightMode but in UiModeManager I cant find setApplicationNightMode how can I achieve this?

**Exact issue : After Update My Android Splash Screen API. When I'm Changing the App theme to dark/light which is not reflecting in Splash Screen of My App.Splashscreen is working based on system preference which means if my mobile is in dark mode  -> then my splash screen is in dark and if my mobile is in light mode splash screen is light. how can I resolve the problem.**

Any Suggestion experts?